# Automated sub- and superscripts

Tags: macros

I would like to define a command that prints the first letter of its argument as superscript and the last two letters as subscribt. So if I type:

`\mynewcommand{abcde}`

it should do the same as

`\textsuperscript{a}bc\textsubscript{de}`

such a command would save me hours of time, but I don't know how to do it

Edit: Sorry, I probably was not clear, the part in the middle can be everything. So only the first letter should be a superscript and the last two a subscript.

What I need is:

`\anothernewcommand{a some text that can contain \textit{other commands} cd}`

which than should do the same as

`\textsuperscript{a} some text that can contain \textit{other commands} \textsubscript{cd}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that a syntax such as `\mynewcommand{a}{bc}{de}` would be clearer. Anyway, I can offer two implementations that differ in the treatment of spaces after the superscript and before the subscript. Take your pick.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mynewcommandA}{m}
 {
  \textsuperscript{\tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { 1 } }
  \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 2 } { -3 }
  \textsubscript{\tl_range:nnn { #1 } { -2 } { -1 } }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\mynewcommandB}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } { \c_space_tl }
  \textsuperscript{\tl_range:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { 1 } { 1 } }
  \tl_range:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { 2 } { -3 }
  \textsubscript{\tl_range:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { -2 } { -1 } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\textbf{Leading and trailing spaces are not kept}

\mynewcommandA{abcde}

\mynewcommandA{a some text that can contain \textit{other commands} cd}

\bigskip

\textbf{Leading and trailing spaces are kept}

\mynewcommandB{abcde}

\mynewcommandB{a some text that can contain \textit{other commands} cd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some more information. The function `\tl_range:nnn` takes three arguments where the first is some text, the second and third are integers that specify the range to extract; so `{1}{1}` extracts the first item (it can also be `\tl_head:n`, but I used the more complex function for uniformity), whereas `{-2}{-1}` specifies the last two items (with negative indices the extraction starts from the end); `{2}{-3}` specifies the range from the second item to the third starting from the right.

However, in order to keep spaces at the boundaries of the extracted parts, we have to first replace spaces with `\c_space_tl`, which will expand to a space, but is not trimmed by the extraction functions. The syntax of `\tl_set:Nnn` is the same, only the first argument has to be a tl variable.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much! Using \ newcommand {a} {bc} {d} would be clearer, but actually a lot of work. Now I only have to change one command in the preamble, otherwise I would have to go through the entire document and put new brackets

Comment: How might your code be extended to handle general utf8-encode strings, e.g., "öçäßüéà"?

Comment: @Mico Not easy at all with `pdflatex`

Comment: It may be useful to note that if anyone wishes to use your solution with general utf8-encoded character strings, all they have to do is switch from `pdflatex` to either `lualatex` or `xelatex`; no need to modify the workings of `\mynewcommandA` and `\mynewcommandB`. Of course, if a document contains lots of non-ascii utf8-encoded characters, they may already be using `lualatex` or `xelatex` (along with the `fontspec` package and a suitable OpenType font).

Answer (score 5):

For sake of complexity, I show how to solve this problem at TeX primitive level:

```
\newcount\bufflen

\def\splitbuff #1#2{% #1: number of tokens from end, #2 data
                    % result: \buff, \restbuff
    \edef\buff{\detokenize{#2} }%
    \edef\buff{\expandafter}\expandafter\protectspaces \buff \\
    \bufflen=0 \expandafter\setbufflen\buff\end
    \advance\bufflen by-#1\relax
    \ifnum\bufflen<0 \errmessage{#1>buffer length}\fi
    \ifnum\bufflen>0 \edef\buff{\expandafter}\expandafter\splitbuffA \buff\end
    \else \let\restbuff=\buff \def\buff{}\fi
    \edef\tmp{\gdef\noexpand\buff{\buff}\gdef\noexpand\restbuff{\restbuff}}%
    {\endlinechar=-1 \scantokens\expandafter{\tmp}}%
}

\def\protectspaces #1 #2 {\addto\buff{#1}%
    \ifx\\#2\else \addto\buff{{ }}\afterfi \protectspaces #2 \fi}  
\def\afterfi #1\fi{\fi#1}
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\setbufflen #1{%
    \ifx\end#1\else \advance\bufflen by1 \expandafter\setbufflen\fi}

\def\splitbuffA #1{\addto\buff{#1}\advance\bufflen by-1
    \ifnum\bufflen>0 \expandafter\splitbuffA
    \else \expandafter\splitbuffB \fi
}
\def\splitbuffB #1\end{\def\restbuff{#1}}

% --------------- \mynewcommand implementation:

\def\textup#1{$^{\rm #1}$}  \def\textdown#1{$_{\rm #1}$}
\def\mynewcommand#1{\mynewcommandA#1\end}
\def\mynewcommandA#1#2\end{%
   \textup{#1}\splitbuff 2{#2}\buff \textdown{\restbuff}}

% --------------- test:

\mynewcommand{abcde}

\mynewcommand{a some text that can contain {\it other commands} cd}

\bye
```

Comment: +1 for "for the sake of complexity". Good one! :-)

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It sets up a Lua function which, in turn, makes use of Lua's string functions `string.sub` and `string.len` to accomplish its task. It also sets up a LaTeX "wrapper" macro called `\mynewcommand`, which expands its argument once before passing it to the Lua function.

The solution actually employs variants of the Lua string functions, `unicode.utf8.sub` and `unicode.utf8.len`, to allow the argument of `\mynewcommand` to be any valid string of utf8-encoded characters. (Of course, in order to *print* the characters in the string, a suitable font has to be loaded.) The argument of `\mynewcommand` may contain primitives and macros.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for "\luaexec" and "\luastringO" macros
\luaexec{
% Define a Lua function called "mycommand"
function mycommand ( s )
   local s1,s2,s3
   s1  = unicode.utf8.sub ( s, 1, 1 )
   s2  = unicode.utf8.sub ( s, 2, unicode.utf8.len(s)-2 )
   s3  = unicode.utf8.sub ( s, -2 )
   return ( "\\textsuperscript{" ..s1.. "}" ..s2.. "\\textsubscript{" ..s3.. "}" )
end
}
% Create a wrapper macro for the Lua function
\newcommand\mynewcommand[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(mycommand(\luastringO{#1}))}}
    
\begin{document}
abcde $\to$ \mynewcommand{abcde}

öçäßüéà $\to$ \mynewcommand{öçäßüéà}

\mynewcommand{a some text that can contain \textit{\textbf{other commands}} cd}
\end{document}
```